# setw not working properly

Tags: c++, c++11

Im writing a loan amortization program but when I use "setw" to set up my columns its putting "month" and "Current Balance" together and not spacing the others like I want.

I included a picture below of the output on the terminal.

```
cout << "Month" // sets up columns
     << setw(15) << "Current Balance"
     << setw(15) << "Interest"
     << setw(15) << "Payment"
     << setw(15) << "New Balance \n" << endl;


int month_count = 1;
while( month_count <= number_of_months) // Loops while calculating the monthly interest and new balances produced after payments.
    {
    cout << month_count
         << setw(15) << loan_amount;

    double interest = loan_amount * monthly_rate;

    cout << setw(15) << interest
         << setw(15) << payment;

    loan_amount = loan_amount + interest - payment;

    cout << setw(15) << loan_amount << endl;

    month_count++;
    }
```

OUTPUT

[image: Here is how its aligning]

Comment: You `setw` for every item in the print statement except the first, so the first is sized according to how many characters it needs. Only those that follow are padded to 15 characters.

Comment: Besides, "Current Balance" is 15 chars long, so it's printed after "month" without any space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a few things:

1st: Increase your width to something slightly longer than the maximum width of your column names. In this case you have "Current Balance" which is 15 characters long, so if you use 15 as your field width, you won't get spacing around that column.

2nd: Use `std::setw` together with `std::left` for your first column to space our that column too. (`std::left` will left-justify the first column)

3rd: Use `std::setw` together with `std::right` for your value columns to right align the values, and use a combination of `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision(2)` to always print 2 decimal places for your dollar/cent amounts, which makes it easier to read

**Here is an example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int number_of_months = 3;
double loan_amount = 50;
double monthly_rate = 2.3;
double payment = 10;

int main()
{
    cout << setw(7)  << std::left << "Month" // sets up columns
         << setw(17) << std::right << "Current Balance"
         << setw(17) << std::right << "Interest"
         << setw(17) << std::right << "Payment"
         << setw(17) << std::right << "New Balance" << '\n' << endl;


    int month_count = 1;
    while( month_count <= number_of_months) // Loops while calculating the monthly interest and new balances produced after payments.
    {
        cout << setw(7) << std::left << month_count
             << setw(17) << std::right << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << loan_amount;

        double interest = loan_amount * monthly_rate;

        cout << setw(17) << std::right << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << interest
             << setw(17) << std::right << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << payment;

        loan_amount = loan_amount + interest - payment;

        cout << setw(17) << std::right << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << loan_amount << endl;

        month_count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Month    Current Balance         Interest          Payment      New Balance

1                  50.00           115.00            10.00           155.00
2                 155.00           356.50            10.00           501.50
3                 501.50          1153.45            10.00          1644.95
```

Comment: I think the `std::left` modifier is the default one and can be left out.